# Why am I getting NaN when adding all arguments?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that adds all arguments together. I keep getting `NaN`. What am I doing wrong?

```
function sum() {
       var n = arguments.length;
       var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // code here
        total += n[i];
    }
    return total;
}

sum(1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: `console.log(n); console.log(n[i]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get value from **[`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)**, where `n` is just a number holds the length of **[`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)** and `n[i]` will be `undefined`. Addition with `undefined` results `NaN`.

```js
function sum() {
  var n = arguments.length;
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // code here
    total += arguments[i];
  }
  return total;
}

console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

What is `n[i];` ? As `n` should only contain length of arguments `array`, its not itself an `array`.

You need to replace `total += n[i];` with `total += arguments[i];`

Answer (score 0):

One of the classic disadvantage of javaScript is about NaN(Not a Number)'s underlying principle is.

NaN(Not equal to anything)-->When it occurs
i)Result of undefined or erroneous operations

ii)Toxic :any arithmetic operations with Nan as input will have NaN as a result.

So in your code:undefined(n[i])+number=NaN

```
<script>

        function sum() {
            var n = arguments.length;
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                // code here
                total += arguments[i];
            }
            return total;//returns 10
        }
        sum(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Hope this helps/serves the purpose